# enable mini profiler only to specific user and roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler

In asp.net mvc the scott hanselman example shows how to show the mini profiler for a local environmnet

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.IsLocal) { MiniProfiler.Start(); } //or any number of other checks, up to you 
        }
```

But, I would like to go a step further and be able to see it remotely, only for specific logged in users, or ips.

Any idea how?

Update: I used the following code:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            MiniProfiler.Stop(); //stop as early as you can, even earlier with MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsAuthorizedUserForMiniProfiler(this.Context))
            {
                MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);
            }
        }

        private bool IsAuthorizedUserForMiniProfiler(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.Name.Equals("levalencia"))
                return true;
            else
                return context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `PostAuthorizeRequest` event and discard the results if the current user is not in a given role or the request is coming from a specific IP or whatever check you want:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Start();  
}

protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!DoTheCheckHere(this.Context))
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: true);
    }
}

private bool DoTheCheckHere(HttpContext context)
{
    // do your checks here
    return context.User.IsInRole("Admin");
}
```

Comment: how can I get the current user from the global.asax?

Comment: User is not a class inside Request?, am I missing an assembly reference or an using I suppose?

Comment: I see this: context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.,maybe this one works for the user, but the IsInRole method does not exist when I try to use this

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, `User` is property of the `HttpContext`, not of the `Request`. It should be `context.User.IsInRole("Admin")`.

Comment: yes, it works now :), pls check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897328/mini-profiler-is-appearing-twice-on-the-screen